# Sublime snippet in many places with different placeholders

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

In my scaffolding snippet I'd like to be able to remove two chunks of optional code, with a single button press. However my attempts were unsuccessful.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
MainContent {
    ${1:${2:Feature}}
}

SecondaryContent {
    ${1:${3:FeatureRelatedContent}}
}
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>hello</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.mudkipz</scope>
</snippet>
```

At the moment I achieve it with this:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
MainContent {
    ${1:Feature}
}

SecondaryContent {
    ${1/.+/FeatureRelatedContent/}
}
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>test</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.js</scope>
</snippet>
```

However for bigger chunks of code, escaping is a little tedious. Anybody knows a better solution?

Comment: Could you demonstrate the tediousness that you are trying to avoid?